# Cannot implicitly convert object to string

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I get this message in the following when I try to do this

```
ThisString= reader["ThisString"];
```

In the following:

```
    string ThisString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table WHERE parameter=@parameter", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", parameter);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ThisString= reader["ThisString"];
                }
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving the error because retrieving an item from reader by string index returns as type object as shown by the following [signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public override Object this[string name] { get; }
```

Typically, to easily convert from object to string you would call `.ToString()` on the result.

```
ThisString = reader["ThisString"].ToString();
```

However, since this is unsafe when working with SqlDataReader as it will not handle Null Reference Exceptions or DBNull, you should use the [GetOrdinal()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getordinal(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of your reader.

```
var ordinal = reader.GetOrdinal("ThisString")
if (ordinal > -1)
{
    ThisString = reader.GetString(ordinal);
}
```

By checking for the ordinal of the column in the data reader, you are ensuring that your target column is present.  If the value is -1, it is not present and you should not attempt to call `GetString()`.

Comment: please do never read Data from a Database like that. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: @swe The OP never asked about the CORRECT methodology for retrieving strings from the database but rather how to solve the specific error that he was getting.  However, I've updated my answer to the "correct" methodology.

Answer (score 1):

```
ThisString= Convert.ToString(reader["ThisString"]);
```

That will also save you from [Null Reference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), In case of `DBNull.Value`, you will get an empty string back.

You can also utilize `SqlDataReader.GetString` method and specify the column index.

```
ThisString= reader.GetString(0);//assuimg 0 is the column index
```

Or use `SqlDataReader.GetOridnal` method to get column index, and then use `reader.GetString`.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlReader [has methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) to read Strings and other strongly typed objects from it.

Try use `reader.IsDBNull(ColIndex)` to check for DBNull

Try use `reader.GetString(ColIndex)` to read a string from the database

Try use `reader.GetOrdinal("ThisString")` to read the ColumnIndex of your column.